# Что сделать при ошибке displ is ininitialized. Always initialize a member variable?

Tags: c++

Что сделать при ошибке displ is ininitialized. Always initialize a member variable?
ниже представлен код программы:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std;
  
class Sheep {
    char* name;
    int displ;
public:
    Sheep() {
        cout << "Конструктор без параметров" << endl;
    }
    Sheep(const char* Name, int Displ) {
        name = new char[strlen(Name) + 1];
        name = strcpy(name, Name);
        displ = Displ;
        cout << "Конструктор с параметами" << endl;
    }
    Sheep(const Sheep& s) {
        name = s.name;
        displ = s.displ;
        cout << "Конструктор копирования" << endl;
    }
    ~Sheep() {
        cout << "Вызван деструктор" << endl;
    }
 
};
int main()
{
    Sheep shееp;
    Sheep shееp2("you", 12);
    Sheep shееp3(shееp2);
}
```

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://godbolt.org/z/77zzcv)

Comment: логично. Просто нужно ещё и компилятор угадать. Такая ошибка генерируется студией (https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/code-quality/c26495?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score -2):

Напишите конструктор по умолчанию ("конструктор без параметров") полностью. Где то так

```
Sheep() : name{nullptr}, displ{0} {
    cout << "Конструктор без параметров" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Товарищи минусаторы, ставите минус - пишите, что Вам не нравится. Телепаты то в отпуске